# How to update multiple rows each with different where condition in oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a list of int and list of string in c#  where int is primary key and string is name.

For ex: {1,2},{"fist", "second"}

```
update table set name ="first" where id =1  
update table set name = "second" where id=2
```

I need to update the values in oracle using the procedure.

Suppose i have procedure as follows  with  list passed as array to varchar

PROCEDURE updateName
 (
  id IN VARCHAR,
  name IN VARCHAR
 )
  IS
   BEGIN
 END updatename.

What is the logic I should imply without using case statement

Comment: what is the problem? dont you know how update with ado.net?

Comment: I need to do bulk update in single procedure

Comment: You shouldn't even need a procedure for this, it's a simple SQL statement. (However that is done in ado.net, with which I am not familiar.)

Comment: You need [**DataAdapters**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2(v=vs.110).aspx), convert your dictionary into a `data table`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so perhaps you have a table (whose name better not be "table"!) - let's say it's called tbl, with at least two columns, id and name. And you have a dictionary, with columns id and name (or whatever other column names).

Then - using the `merge` statement:

```
merge into tbl
  using dictionary
    on (tbl.id = dictionary.id)
when matched then
  update set name = dictionary.name
;
```

You could also use an `update` statement, but when the update reads from another table, `merge` is easier to read and maintain, and sometimes it may also be more efficient.

Comment: I almost sure dictionary is a `C#` list

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - then the OP (or someone familiar with ado.net and C# - to - Oracle) will show how to "see" the C# list as a view or a temp table.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - of course, that is what I **meant** to write. Fixing it now.

Comment: I need to pass dictionary of int,string in c# code to oracle procedure as varchar or any other data type and do the update efficiently with out case statement as I will be having lots of data.

Comment: I know a little c# but from different context, I haven't used it with Oracle. If you know how to pass the data from c# to create a temporary table in Oracle, you can use the `merge` statement as above.

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL way would be:

```
UPDATE table 
SET name =
    CASE WHEN id=1 THEN "first" 
    CASE WHEN id=2 THEN "second"
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2)
```

Another option would be to create a temp table, insert all of the key-value pairs, and do a `JOIN` in the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @mathguy Not for a computer :)

Comment: Oh - if the computer will generate the code, then I agree. :-)